# Screenshot of a udp live stream from VLC,using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, vlc

I want to take a screenshot of a network stream,that is playing on VLC,on udp protocol,using ffmpeg.
I'm able to save the recorded stream using the following command.

```
ffmpeg -i udp://ip:port -c copy file_name.ts
```

But is there a way to take the screenshot without saving the file.I don't want to take thumbnails.Thank You for your hrlp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run

```
ffmpeg -i udp://ip:port -vframes 1 -q:v 1 screenshot.jpg
```